# how can you use the text written in <textarea></textarea> as a value in javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

Hello i am very new to programming / coding and i would like to know how you would be able to how can you use the  as a value in JavaScript. This is for a typing game where i want to find out how to find the value only of what was written inside of the . I have tried using this code but it hasnt worked

HTML
`<textarea class="text-box" rows="8" cols="55"></textarea>`

JavaScript

```
let typedText = document.getElementsByClassName("text-box")[0];
let textValue = typedText.value;
console.log(textValue);
```

Comment: When are you running this code specifically?

Comment: "but it hasnt worked": please provide details.

Comment: @Scott Hunter - originally when i ran the code when i typed in the<textarea> element it wouldn't display anything in the console. I want it to be able to be displayed in the console. Or at least have a value which i can use.

Comment: @Unmitigated - well the code is intended for a typing game where i need to create a value for the text typed in <textarea>. BTW the console.log(it just for this demonstration to simplify it);. So i want the text to work when a button is pressed. Then there is going to be a three second countdown and then the i want the code to run. I have already created that code so i didn't include it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript code looks good. But it has no entry point. You are running it at the beginning once and never again. What you want is to **LISTEN** to changes in the text area and then act accordingly.

Create a method. Use it as an [event listener](https://www.scaler.com/topics/event-listener-in-javascript/) by listening to one of the textarea events such as `change` or `input`.

Here is a simple demo:

```js
const run = () => {
let typedText = document.getElementsByClassName("text-box")[0];
let textValue = typedText.value;
console.log(textValue);
};
```

```html
<textarea class="text-box" rows="8" cols="55" oninput="run()"></textarea>
```